# How can I debug tests in Visual Studio Code with a serverless-framework project using the serverless-bundle package?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jestjs, serverless-framework

I have a serverless-framework project that is using the serverless-bundle package so that I can use ES6 imports and exports.

I currently have a failing test. When I click on the "Debug" link in Visual Studio Code, the debug session fails for the following reason on line 1 of my test code: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

The test code I'm working on is located here: https://github.com/groffcole/art-center-service/blob/master/ports/GalleriesHttpPort.test.js

What can I do to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try using const "" = require() and see if that works. if it does, what version of nodejs do you have installed? and did you set it up to use es6 imports? ES^ imports are still experimental as of node 13
https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_introduction
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v13.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports

```
let func1 = ()=>{
return "Hello"
}
let func2 = ()=>{
return "World"
}
module.exports ={func1:func1,func2:func2}
```

Comment: I tried this and am still receiving a similar error. I'm curious, why can I run the tests just fine using `npm test` but the debugger in VS Code isn't happy?

Comment: what version of Node is this?

Comment: whats this? import UUID from "uuid/v4";

Comment: I have version 13.7.0 installed. This is the test script from my `package.json` file: `"test": "serverless-bundle test"`

Comment: `import UUID from "uuid/v4"` is from this package: https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#readme. It looks like maybe I should use a different import statement like this: `import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';`. But this seems to not bother my other tests I've written, for example: https://github.com/groffcole/art-center-service/blob/master/adaptors/GalleriesHttpAdaptor.test.js

Comment: I would update that too. I would also check with the nodejs 13 docs on how they handle multiple exports. if im writing in JavaScript ( normally i use Typescript) ill do my exports like:
    module.exports ={ func1,func2,func3...}